# Is it possible to use Skip and Take whilst calculating an Average?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to create query using LINQ to Entities that calculates an average of a rating for a product. I project the average for each product to an anonymous object, before ordering the ratings. I then want to take only a portion of the results.

The query is below:

```
var query = Items.GroupBy(review => review.Product)
            .Select(group => new
            {
                Product = group.Key,
                Rating = group.Average(review => review.Rating)
            })
            .OrderByDescending(pr => pr.Rating)
            .Skip(itemsToSkip)
            .Take(count)
            .ToList();
```

The query that is generated looks like the following:

```sql
{SELECT 
1 AS [C1], 
[GroupBy1].[K1] AS [ProductId], 
[GroupBy1].[K2] AS [TotalImages], 
[GroupBy1].[K3] AS [TotalVideos], 
[GroupBy1].[K4] AS [TotalAudioRecordings], 
[GroupBy1].[K5] AS [Name], 
[GroupBy1].[K6] AS [DiscountedPrice], 
[GroupBy1].[K7] AS [Status], 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C2]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent2].[ProductId] AS [K1], 
    [Extent2].[TotalImages] AS [K2], 
    [Extent2].[TotalVideos] AS [K3], 
    [Extent2].[TotalAudioRecordings] AS [K4], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [K5], 
    [Extent2].[DiscountedPrice] AS [K6], 
    [Extent2].[Status] AS [K7], 
    AVG([Extent1].[Rating]) AS [A1]
    FROM  [dbo].[ProductReviews] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Product_ProductId] = [Extent2].[ProductId]
    GROUP BY [Extent2].[ProductId], [Extent2].[TotalImages], [Extent2].[TotalVideos], [Extent2].[TotalAudioRecordings], [Extent2].[Name], [Extent2].[DiscountedPrice], [Extent2].[Status]
)  AS [GroupBy1]}
```

The query doesn't work to skip any items, or to take only a few results. Rather it returns a calculation of the average for every product in the database.

Is it possible to utilise `Skip` and `Take`, as I am attempting to do? If so, how do I correct the query to get the desired result? It is desirable that I do not pull back all the data from the database.

Comment: The query should work the way it's written. What EF version are you using?

Comment: @IvanStoev EF 6.1.3.

Comment: Then it works for me the way it is.

Comment: My test data had 50 products in it, with 50 ratings for each product. When I passed 0 for itemsToSkip and count of 10, it would return all 50 products. When I altered my code to include an additional select as per the only answer posted so far the code returned 10 products.

Comment: My point is that in my test environment the generated query always contains `ORDER BY` and either `TOP` or `OFFSET FETCH` clause. Including additional select makes no any sense, it will be interesting to hear how @CodingYoshi get to that "brilliant" idea - when you do such things, it usually means workarounding the 3rd party bug, that's why asked for the version and checked against it. To recap, the issue is non reproducible for me - it should not happen and the "fix" should not fix it :) Good luck.

Comment: @IvanStoev The reason I posted the question was that I expected something like what you're describing. But that wasn't happening. So I thought it was something I had done wrong. I'm interested to hear what I should be looking at if the query actually works for you? :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135489/discussion-between-darren-gansberg-and-ivan-stoev).

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to add one more select to your query:

```
var query = Items.GroupBy(review => review.Product)
.Select(group => new
{
    Product = group.Key,
    Rating = group.Average(review => review.Rating)
})
.OrderByDescending(pr => pr.Rating)
.Select(x => new { Product = x.Product, Rating = x.Rating })
.Skip(itemsToSkip)
.Take(count)
.ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this will actually perform but initial testing looks good. Could you perhaps explain the rationale behind the second select?